# How to encrypt and decrypt all API trequest and response in SAP hybris?

Tags: encryption, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, api-security

I have a security requirement that all the data flows through API should be encrypted. I don't see any OOTB implementation. So I have thought about having a filter to decrypt and a custom sanitizer to encrypt sounded like a plan but are there any other ways to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS protocol already has encryption. If you want to make it more, secure maybe you can add a client certificate option.